# "It would be great if there were and other sessions like that in the future! "

Tags: phrases

Could I say the sentence below, or it sounds totally wrong?

"It would be great if there were and other sessions like that in the future!"

Should I say "more" instead of "and other"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"And other" isn't grammatical. Do you mean "*another*"?

- "Another session" would mean one more additional session.
- "More sessions" would mean more than one additional sessions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wanted to say more than one additional sessions. So I should write it like that "It would be great if there were more sessions like that in the future", right??

Comment: @bkostas exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be great if there were and other sessions like that in the future!

'and other' is incorrect. If you are trying to say you want to see more such sessions then:

> It would be great if there were more sessions like that in the future!

If you wish to say you want to see one other session like that in particular, then:

> It would be great if there was another session like that in the future!